# How to user prettier to format code on the clientside?

Tags: javascript, prettier

I am developing a simple in-browser dev environment and want to run prettier on code inside my browser in the clientside. How would i do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got this to work. Prettier can run on a string.

Comment: I'd like to know how you manage to run the Prettier on the Client side. Can you post an example to it?